# How to get the after question mark value PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I need the value of `add_cart` after the question mark?

```
echo "<a  href='index.php?add_cart=<?php echo $pro_id; ?>' name='shto' class='sp' '><button style='float:right;'>Cart</button></a>  ";
```

Something like this

```
$value = add_cart;
```

Comment: Here is your startpoint: [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) ... Let us know if you found the endpoint or if you need some additional help

Comment: the add_cart variable is under echo, when I try to access it outside of echo, it says that add_cart is an unidentified index !

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
$value = 4544545; //the item number
echo "<a  href='index.php?add_cart=$value' name='shto' class='sp' '><button style='float:right;'>Cart</button></a>  ";
```

And in index.php you get the value with:

```
$valueFromAddCart = $_GET['add_cart'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$_GET`

example:

```
$value = $_GET['add_cart'];
```